# AWS BOTO3 - getting InvalidArgumentBucket POST must contain a field named 'key'

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a lambda function that then creates a html page for uploading a file to s3, and adds the fields needed for the authentication (like the key etc). However I keep getting the error:
AWS BOTO3 - getting InvalidArgumentBucket POST must contain a field named 'key'.

This is my HTML form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action='https://modit-images.s3.amazonaws.com/' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Select image to upload:
    <input type='file' name='file'>
    <input type='hidden' name='key' value='123123111515164684'> 
    <input type='hidden' name='AWSAccessKeyId' value='ASIAQURPAJ6RWDOSXB7P'>
    <input type='hidden' name='x-amz-security-token' value='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'> 
    <input type='hidden' name='policy' value='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'> 
    <input type='hidden' name='signature' value='JNUqFEv2mEvNeM1l1W9SYxPP6iU='> 
    <input type='submit' value='Upload Image' name='submit'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the python code that throws the boto3 error?

Comment: Can you share the code/action which is triggered from "https://modit-images.s3.amazonaws.com/" and does the job of upload. The html is not useful.